# Autotools puts -l flags for linked libraries at the wrong place in the compile command

Tags: fortran, fortran90, autotools, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I try to compile a Fortran 90 program using autotools. My makefile.am is here :

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign subdir-objects
bin_PROGRAMS = medys
medys_SOURCES =   src/all_v001/basics.f90 src/all_v001/variables.f90 src/all_v001/read_input.f90 src/all_v001/math.f90 src/all_v001/champ1.f90 src/all_v001/grille.f90 src/all_v001/NewSubroutines.f90 src/all_v001/Tests.f90 src/all_v001/string.f90 src/all_v001/io_module.f90 src/all_v001/precision.f90 src/core/error.f90 src/all_v001/matrix_modifications.f90 src/all_v001/matrix_temp_lowlvl.f90 src/all_v001/matrix_temp_highlvl.f90 src/all_v001/read_columbus.f90 src/all_v001/ortho.f90 src/all_v001/qp_integrals.f90 src/all_v001/observable.f90 src/all_v001/nouveaudrt.f90 src/all_v001/read_gamess.f90 src/all_v001/dynamique.f90  src/main/main.f90

AM_FCFLAGS =  -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/lib/intel64 -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/include/intel64/lp64/ -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -liomp5 -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -nogen-interface -fpe0  -traceback -debug extended -heap-arrays -fp-stack-check -debug all -openmp
```

and my configure.ac is here:

```
AC_INIT([medys], [0.1], [meitnerium109@gmail.com])
m4_define([_AC_F95_FC], [ifort])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/main/main.f90])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_FC
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Every .o file compiles correctly, but for the bin files compilation fails. If I do the compilation manually, but adding `FLAG` at the end of the compilation, the compilation is successful. With the `make` command, the compilation fails:

```
ifort -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/lib/intel64 -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/include/intel64/lp64/ -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -liomp5 -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -nogen-interface -fpe0  -traceback -debug extended -heap-arrays -fp-stack-check -debug all -openmp  -g -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/lib/intel64 -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/include/intel64/lp64/  -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -liomp5 -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64  -o medys src/all_v001/basics.o src/all_v001/variables.o src/all_v001/read_input.o src/all_v001/math.o src/all_v001/champ1.o src/all_v001/grille.o src/all_v001/NewSubroutines.o src/all_v001/Tests.o src/all_v001/string.o src/all_v001/io_module.o src/all_v001/precision.o src/core/error.o src/all_v001/matrix_modifications.o src/all_v001/matrix_temp_lowlvl.o src/all_v001/matrix_temp_highlvl.o src/all_v001/read_columbus.o src/all_v001/ortho.o src/all_v001/qp_integrals.o src/all_v001/observable.o src/all_v001/nouveaudrt.o src/all_v001/read_gamess.o src/all_v001/dynamique.o src/main/main.o
```

with lof of message error like this one

```
src/main/main.f90:471: undefined reference to `zgemm_mkl95_'
```

But if I put the compilation flag at the end, the compilation works:

```
 ifort -o medys src/all_v001/basics.o src/all_v001/variables.o src/all_v001/read_input.o src/all_v001/math.o src/all_v001/champ1.o src/all_v001/grille.o src/all_v001/NewSubroutines.o src/all_v001/Tests.o src/all_v001/string.o src/all_v001/io_module.o src/all_v001/precision.o src/core/error.o src/all_v001/matrix_modifications.o src/all_v001/matrix_temp_lowlvl.o src/all_v001/matrix_temp_highlvl.o src/all_v001/read_columbus.o src/all_v001/ortho.o src/all_v001/qp_integrals.o src/all_v001/observable.o src/all_v001/nouveaudrt.o src/all_v001/read_gamess.o src/all_v001/dynamique.o src/main/main.o -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/lib/intel64 -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/include/intel64/lp64/ -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -liomp5 -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64 -nogen-interface -fpe0  -traceback -debug extended -heap-arrays -fp-stack-check -debug all -openmp  -g -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/lib/intel64 -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/include/intel64/lp64/  -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -liomp5 -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64
```

autotools use the following command for the compilation :

```
$(FC) $(AM_FCFLAGS) $(FCFLAGS) -c $(FCFLAGS_f90) $<
```

Can I change it? Do you have other suggestion?

Comment: How does it fail? Where is the error message? Do not use pastebin, include all necessary information in the question itself.

Comment: Please find some better title, do not just repeat tags, describe your actual problem with them.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I edited the question, with explicit error.

Comment: The order of the flags passed to the compiler does matter. You should always put the object file which needs a symbol from a library and only after that the `-l` flag for the library that supplies the symbol. That's why you need the flags at the end of the command. I don't know how that is done in autotools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AM_FCFLAGS` should really only contain the -I flags, and even then only those that are essential for your build local system structure (aka, all those flags will use `$(top_srcdir)` most likely.

When you want to link with a third party library, you should pass the
compiler flags (which include the -I flags) to FCFLAGS and linker flags to LDADD, for example

```
medys_FCFLAGS = -I/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/include/intel64/lp64/ -nogen-interface -fpe0  -traceback -debug extended -heap-arrays -fp-stack-check -debug all -openmp
medys_LDADD = -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -liomp5 -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64
```

or something along those lines.

I'm a C++ coder, but there isn't much difference there (I just have to use  CXX where you use FC). Here is an example of how a good Makefile.am looks like: https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-xml/blob/master/Makefile.am

As you can see, all my third party library flags, compiler and linker alike, are AC_SUBST's from configure.ac. For example, the BOOST*, LIBXML_CFLAGS and LIBXML_LIBS in there are set by having this included (with m4_include()) in my configure.ac: https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-xml/blob/master/configure.m4

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer helped me a lot. I will look at your Makefile to improve mine.